Алгоритм нейгла не выключаеться
Написал вот такой код для отправки больших массивов данных по TCP сокету:
public async Task SendMessage(TcpClient client, string? packetid, string message)
{
    if (client == null || !client.Connected) return;
    if (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message).Length + Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"singlemessage¶|~{packetid}¶|~").Length > buffersize)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        Random random = new Random();
        string startmessage;
        string dataid = $"id{random.Next(1, 999999999)}";
        if (packetid != null)   { startmessage = $"startlistening¶|~{dataid}¶|~{packetid}"; }
        else                    { startmessage = $"startlistening¶|~{dataid}¶|~nullid"; }
        await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(startmessage), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(startmessage).Length);
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        int chunkSize = buffersize - Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"appenddata¶|~{dataid}¶|~").Length;
        int bytesSent = 0;

        while (bytesSent < messageBytes.Length)
        {
            int bytesToSend = Math.Min(chunkSize, messageBytes.Length - bytesSent);
            var dataToSend = new List<byte>();
            dataToSend.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"appenddata¶|~{dataid}¶|~"));
            dataToSend.AddRange(messageBytes.Skip(bytesSent).Take(bytesToSend));
            await stream.WriteAsync(dataToSend.ToArray(), 0, dataToSend.Count);

            bytesSent += bytesToSend;
        }

        await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"enddata¶|~{dataid}"), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"enddata¶|~{dataid}").Length);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            string fullmessage;
            if (packetid != null)   { fullmessage = $"singlemessage¶|~{packetid}¶|~{message}"; }
            else                    { fullmessage = $"singlemessage¶|~nullid¶|~{message}"; }
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fullmessage);

            await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        catch{ }
    }
}

Однако столкнулся с проблемой, что сообщения, сливаються в одно, при вызове:
await server.SendMessage(client, null, string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(message, 250)));

Получаю что то такое:

Пробовал отключить алгоритм нейгла:
private async Task ListenForConnectionsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        while (_isRunning)
        {
            var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            client.NoDelay = true;
            await HandleClientAsync(client);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

Но это не решило мою проблему. Есть идея с тем чтоб просто засирать пустое место в буфере юзлес символами, и удалять их после получения пакета, но честно говоря эта идея мне не очень нравиться.

TCP является потоковым протоколом. Никогда нельзя расчитывать, что получение данных будет происходить такими же кусками, как при отправке. Включение/выключение алгоритма Нейгла на это никак не влияет.

а как тогда решить эту проблему? использование UDP мне не подходит, мне важна целостность данных, и даже утрата одного пакета сильно повлияет на работу приложения

В ответе в принципе идея правильно описана - сначала отправлять длину сообщения, а затем тело сообщения.

Идея крайне сомнительная, особенно при отправке маленьких сообщений, задержка будет в 2 раза больше

Это обычный подход, который повсеместно используется. С чего вы вдруг решили, что задержка (задержка чего именно?) будет в 2 раза больше - неизвестно.

Под задержкой я имел ввиду пинг (момент с отправки сообщения до момента прихода сообщения), разве отправка двух пакетов вместо одного не увеличивает пинг?

Пинг зависит он расстояния и качетсва сетевого соединения. А два вызова Write не подразумевают, что будет отправлено два пакета. Если алгоритм Нейгла не выключать, то длина наверняка попадет в один пакет с началом тела сообщения. Вызов Write - это не отправка пакета, это дописывание в конец потока.

Кстати да, не подумал о том что они отправяться одним пакетом, просто будут разделены буфером, был не прав

Даже если они попадут в разные пакеты, то на стороне клиента это будет не важно, он об этом даже не узнает.
